# Make link, that is lower than parent divs z-index, clickable

Tags: hyperlink, z-index

I have a link that sits behind another div in z-index terms but I can't seem to make it clickable. The button is the "read more" at the bottom right of the banner. Any help greatly appreciated.
http://bit.ly/181e1Rw

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the z-index of the link's class to something higher than the div it is inside of.

Edit: After looking at the page, to z-index something it has to be "positioned" (I.E. Absolute, relative, or fixed). [Read here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
.someClass { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```